# How to predict numerical value "y"? if I have datasets having different number of parameters

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, regression, linear-regression

I have three excel sheets for training (all numerical values).

- 1st excel sheets have parameters `a, b, c` and output as `y`
- 2nd excel sheet have parameters `a, b, c, d, e` and output as `y`
- 3rd excel sheet have parameters `a, b, c, d` and output as `y`

I have to predict value `y` if values of only `a, b, c` are given.

Should I apply linear regression?

Comment: Thanks. if I remove d,e then it would also impact value y. And how can then I change y. I append all the data into single sheet and put value dummy values 0 for other dependent variable and applied linear regression. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to predict $y$ only given $a,b,c$, then as a first look just discard $d,e$ etc from other data sets*. Any kind of regression might be useful, you will have to explore that - you might as well start with linear regression as it is simplest.

In general, if you are not sure about which algorithm to apply for best results, you should set up an experiment to try multiple models:

- Decide on what "best" means by choosing a test metric (mean square error is a common choice for regression problems).
- Split your data into training, cross-validation and test sets.
- Train different types of model on the training set:

  - Tune any hyper-parameters (of more complex models) by taking the best results from the cross-validation set.
  - Pick your best cross-validation result as your guess at the best model.
- Finally get an unbiased estimate of its performance by using your test set.

---

* There might be ways to use $d,e$ values to refine some models, but if you are at the stage of asking whether or not to use linear regression, this is not worth exploring initially.

Comment: This experimental approach, or variations of it, is how most machine learning model building is done in practice. If this is new to you, and you have further questions about any step, please ask them separately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do process your data first, meaning see if you can combined, as you specified a,b,c,d,e etc these are your independent variables.
2. you know the required output y, thats your dependent variable.
3. you can apply rectifier and sigmoid in ANN
4. and then check for the confusion matrix
5. optimize if required, which i m sure will be required.